# MySQL Single Row Returned From Temporary Table

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am running the following queries against a database:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE med_error_third_party_tmp
SELECT `med_error_category`.description AS category, `med_error_third_party_category`.error_count AS error_count
FROM
    `med_error_category` INNER JOIN `med_error_third_party_category` ON med_error_category.`id` = `med_error_third_party_category`.`category`
WHERE
    year = 2003
GROUP BY `med_error_category`.id;
```

The only problem is that when I create the temporary table and do a select * on it then it returns multiple rows, but the query above only returns one row. It seems to always return a single row unless I specify a GROUP BY, but then it returns a percentage of 1.0 like it should with a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT category, 
       error_count/SUM(error_count) AS percentage
  FROM med_error_third_party_tmp;
```

Here are the server specs:
Server version: 5.0.77
Protocol version: 10
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket

Does anybody see a problem with this that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard SQL requires you to specify a GROUP BY clause if any column is not wrapped in an aggregate function (IE: MIN, MAX, COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc), but [MySQL supports "hidden columns in the GROUP BY"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) -- which is why:

```
SELECT category, 
       error_count/SUM(error_count) AS percentage
  FROM med_error_third_party_tmp;
```

...runs without error. The problem with the functionality is that because there's no GROUP BY, the SUM is the SUM of the error_count column for the entire table.  But the other column values are completely arbitrary - they can't be relied upon.

This:

```
SELECT category, 
       error_count/(SELECT SUM(error_count)
                      FROM med_error_third_party_tmp) AS percentage
  FROM med_error_third_party_tmp;
```

...will give you a percentage on a per row basis -- category values will be duplicated because there's no grouping.

This:

```
  SELECT category, 
         SUM(error_count)/x.total AS percentage
    FROM med_error_third_party_tmp
    JOIN (SELECT SUM(error_count) AS total
            FROM med_error_third_party_tmp) x 
GROUP BY category
```

...will gives you a percentage per category of the sum of the categories error_count values vs the sum of the error_count values for the entire table.

Comment: Ok that makes total sense there about the GROUP BY. I was trying to get the percentage of errors per row of the temporary table divided by the total. As you say though that this cannot be relied upon.

Comment: I was going to be grouping by category also.

Comment: @Khirok: I provided two queries, and explained what you can expect for results from either.

Comment: Thanks first off. Only problem is that I am getting an issue which I assume is because it is trying to open up the temporary table twice. Here is the error: #1137 - Can't reopen table: 'med_error_third_party_tmp'

Comment: @Khirok: Update your question with what you're running - I don't see how either of my queries could return that error, but I don't work with temporary tables...

Comment: Done. Might be that old version of MySQL, a quick google search shows lots of lock issues that were fixed in 5.1.

Comment: @Khirok: I meant query, not the server specs -- sorry.

Comment: Ok had a MySQL guru friend look at it and apparently it is a locking issue. It works fine in 5.1, but 5.0 has issues. So looks like it's time to talk the client into an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it - without the temp table as seperate item...

```
select category, error_count/sum(error_count) "Percentage"
from (SELECT mec.description category
          ,  metpc.error_count 
      FROM med_error_category mec
         , med_error_third_party_category metpc
      WHERE mec.id = metpc.category
      AND year = 2003 
      GROUP BY mec.id
     );
```

i think you will notice that the percentage is unchanging over the categories.  This is probably not what you want - you probably want to group the errors by category as well.